# Matlab Muliple delimiter removing during import

Tags: matlab

I am struggling with a problem and want a easy way around. I have a big array of data where I have some vector values as ( 1.02 1.23 3.32) format. I want it as 1.02 1.23 3.32 in a tabular form. The problem here is that there are two types of delimiter '(' and ')'.

can anyone help in writing a code for this? I have something like this:

```
 filename = 'U.dat';
delimiterIn = '(';
headerlinesIn = 0;
A = textscan(filename,delimiterIn,headerlinesIn);
```

But one thing is that it only have one delimiter "(" and it does not work either.

Nishant

Comment: A longer sample of data and more specific information about the overall format of the file would be helpful in determining the best answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

If your text file looks something like this:

```
(1 2 3) (4 5 6)
(7 8 9) (10 11 12)
```

You can read it in as strings and convert it to a cell array of vectors like this:

```
% read in file
clear all
filename = 'delim.txt';
fid  = fopen(filename); %opens file for reading
tline = fgets(fid); %reads in a line
index = 1; 
 %reads in all lines until the end of the file is reached
while ischar(tline)
    data{index} = tline;     
    tline = fgets(fid);         
    index = index + 1;
end
fclose(fid); %close file

% convert strings to a cell array of vectors
rowIndex = 1;
colIndex = 1;
outData = {};
innerStr = [];

for aCell = data  % for each entry in data
    sline = aCell{1,1}; 
    for c = sline % for each charecter in the line
        if strcmp(c, '(')
            innerStr = [];
        elseif strcmp(c, ')')
            outData{rowIndex,colIndex} = num2str(innerStr);
            colIndex = colIndex + 1;
        else
            innerStr = [innerStr, c];
        end
    end

     rowIndex = rowIndex + 1;
     colIndex = 1;
end

outData
```